# Question on destructuring and handling undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have an application where I'm creating both a back-end API and a front-end React client.

One potential issue I may encounter later revolves around handling undefined destructured variables on the front-end that come from my database (Mongo/Mongoose).

Please review the below code:

```
const createCompany = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // Destructure body content
    const { name, streetAddress1, streetAddress2, city, state, zip } = req.body;
    // Create new company
    const company = new Company({
        name,
        streetAddress1,
        streetAddress2,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
    });
    // Save new company to database
    const createdCompany = await company.save();
    // Send created company data to client
    res.status(201).json(createdCompany);
});
```

streetAddress2 is the only value that is not required in my Company model.

I did a test via Postman and the company is created OK, but when I query the database I notice the "streetAddress2" key is missing. This is fine as I didn't require it, nor did I set a default value.

My question is, once I am on my React front-end and receive the data via Fetch, how should I handle the potentially missing streetAddress2 value? Sometimes it will be there, other times it won't. For example, I'll have a form that'll show all values (name, streetAddress1, streetAddress2, etc).

I plan on destructuring the data received via Fetch in much the same way as I do in the above code.

I suppose a simple ternary that checks if the value is there will suffice and protect against the error.

Is ternary considered a best practice in this scenario or should I be setting a default value of "" for my streetAddress2?

I'm new to back-end JavaScript and appreciate any feedback.

**EDIT**

Thank you very much for the feedback, everyone. The different methods presented certainly helped me frame my thinking on the best way to handle this situation.

I've also created a PUT route for updating companies, which I'll show below. I used some of the ideas presented when creating it.

```
// @desc    Update company by ID
// @route   PUT /api/companies/:id
// @access  Private
const updateCompany = asyncHandler(async (req, res) => {
    // Destructure body content
    const {
        name,
        streetAddress1,
        streetAddress2,
        city,
        state,
        zip,
        isActive,
    } = req.body;
    // Find company by ID
    const company = await Company.findById(req.params.id);
    if (company) {
        // Set updated values if they are defined
        company.name = name || company.name;
        company.streetAddress1 = streetAddress1 || company.streetAddress1;
        company.streetAddress2 = streetAddress2 || company.streetAddress2;
        company.city = city || company.city;
        company.state = state || company.state;
        company.zip = zip || company.zip;
        company.isActive = isActive || company.isActive;

        // Save company to database with updated information
        const updatedCompany = await company.save();
        // Send updated company to client
        res.json(updatedCompany);
    } else {
        res.status(404);
        throw new Error("Company not found");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do Something like this  :

```
apiCall()
.then(response=>{
   const {   name,streetAddress1,streetAddress2,city,state,zip} = response.data
   const  mapedCompanyObject=  {  
        name,
        streetAddress1,
        streetAddress2:streetAddress2?streetAddress2:'',
        city,
        state,
        zip
       }
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You can apply the default value to `streetAddress2`

```
const company = new Company({
    name,
    streetAddress1,
    streetAddress2 || '',
    city,
    state,
    zip,
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose allows you to set [`default values`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/defaults.html) to the fields if undefined, so you can do something like this in your `Company` schema -

```
streetAddress2: {
    type: String,
    default: ''
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!